# Entity Framework and Link Table issue

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ado.net, linq-to-entities

I have a database which consists of the following:

** Table 1 **

- Id (PK)
- Field1

** Table 2 **

- Id (PK)
- Field2

** Link Table **

- Table1Id (FK)
- Table2Id (FK)

The problem is, I cannot access Table 2 from Table 1, even though the relationship exists in the database.

For example, the following should be possible:

```
var Results = from c in DataContext.Table1
              where c.Table2.Field2 == "Test"
              select c;
```

However, "c.Table2.Field2" is not available for some reason - all I get for "c.Table2." is the following (among the standard any<>, where<> et al):

- RelationshipName
- RelationshipSet
- SourceRoleName
- TargetRoleName

So obviously something is screwy somewhere, but I cannot work out what!

Both tables exist in the Entity Schema, and have a valid relationship between them.

Comment: Just to add some information about Entity Framework and link tables - the link table must have a composite primary key of both sides of the relationship, otherwise EF marks it as read only and won't create any relationships through the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `c.Table2.Field2` is not available is that `c.Table2` doesn't have a property called `Field2`. `c.Table2` is a *list* of entities which have that property, not an *instance* of that entity. It's not clear what your intention is here, but I *think* you want:

```
var Results = from c in DataContext.Table1
              where c.Table2.Any(t2 => t2.Field2 == "Test")
              select c;
```